# How to upload files to Amazon S3 using Ruby on Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, amazon-s3

I need to upload files to Amazon S3 from my Ruby on Rails application. I'm using Rails 2.3.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you using an file upload gems?  What is the use case?  Some context will help us help you.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply and I m about to start the application .. Please help I refer many tutorials .. I cant find a gemfile in my app .. plz help

Comment: is it possible to install aws-s3 gem in rails 2.3 ?

Comment: Rails 2.3 is very old now. I would strongly recommend upgrading to Rails 3.1. Many of the new gems work with 3.1. I personally like carrierwave. Also what files are you trying to upload? Images, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Have a look at the "Storage" section.

HTH

Comment: Hi I m a newbe to ruby and can you please explain how to install this paperclip gem ?

Comment: Let me know what you've tried so far and where you are facing challenges, I'll gladly try to help.

Comment: Hi I tried this tutorial (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-music-streaming-app-with-ruby-on-rails/) and getting this error

uninitialized constant SongsController::AWS

Please help

Comment: Paste some code you've got so far and I'll check where you are hitting the error.

Comment: Please provide some details of your environment. Windows or Linux, Ruby version etc.

Comment: I m running ruby in Windows 7 , Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.0

Comment: The tutorial you are using is for Rails 3.0!! so that piece of code will not work for Rails 2.0 code.